# Sentry on-premise docker - NO events

Tags: docker, sentry

I've just installed Sentry 10.1.0.dev0817db07 with this doc: https://docs.sentry.io/server/installation/

And can't get any event into the system.
Everything's seems to work well.

**Installation process:**

```
# ./install.sh
```

Created user account during installation.

```
# docker-compose up -d
```

Nginx proxy is in front with ssl termination.

Everything is up and running:

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
850d124eca33        sentry-onpremise-local                 "/bin/sh -c 'exec /d…"   23 minutes ago      Up 40 seconds       9000/tcp                       sentry_onpremise_post-process-forwarder_1
5b7288291327        sentry-onpremise-local                 "/bin/sh -c 'exec /d…"   23 minutes ago      Up 38 seconds       9000/tcp                       sentry_onpremise_worker_1
5f9749f912b6        sentry-onpremise-local                 "/bin/sh -c 'exec /d…"   23 minutes ago      Up 39 seconds       0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp         sentry_onpremise_web_1
f7d35f91e5d1        sentry-onpremise-local                 "/bin/sh -c 'exec /d…"   23 minutes ago      Up 39 seconds       9000/tcp                       sentry_onpremise_cron_1
71559875a323        sentry-cleanup-onpremise-local         "/entrypoint.sh '0 0…"   23 minutes ago      Up 30 seconds       9000/tcp                       sentry_onpremise_sentry-cleanup_1
b1dbc689da11        getsentry/snuba:latest                 "./docker_entrypoint…"   23 minutes ago      Up 39 seconds       1218/tcp                       sentry_onpremise_snuba-api_1
cedc068beb4d        getsentry/snuba:latest                 "./docker_entrypoint…"   23 minutes ago      Up 39 seconds       1218/tcp                       sentry_onpremise_snuba-replacer_1
9f548504aacb        getsentry/snuba:latest                 "./docker_entrypoint…"   23 minutes ago      Up 39 seconds       1218/tcp                       sentry_onpremise_snuba-outcomes-consumer_1
091a46514621        getsentry/snuba:latest                 "./docker_entrypoint…"   23 minutes ago      Up 39 seconds       1218/tcp                       sentry_onpremise_snuba-consumer_1
b1c3044b07fb        snuba-cleanup-onpremise-local          "/entrypoint.sh '*/5…"   23 minutes ago      Up 30 seconds       1218/tcp                       sentry_onpremise_snuba-cleanup_1
24a537e0fa62        confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.2            "/etc/confluent/dock…"   23 minutes ago      Up 31 seconds       9092/tcp                       sentry_onpremise_kafka_1
cf8e751f0310        symbolicator-cleanup-onpremise-local   "/entrypoint.sh '55 …"   23 minutes ago      Up 30 seconds       3021/tcp                       sentry_onpremise_symbolicator-cleanup_1
469be617741e        tianon/exim4                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 minutes ago      Up 40 seconds       25/tcp                         sentry_onpremise_smtp_1
62008e661796        confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.1.2        "/etc/confluent/dock…"   23 minutes ago      Up 39 seconds       2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp   sentry_onpremise_zookeeper_1
8e618c68a1df        memcached:1.5-alpine                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 minutes ago      Up 40 seconds       11211/tcp                      sentry_onpremise_memcached_1
539e91da6fe7        yandex/clickhouse-server:19.11         "/entrypoint.sh"         23 minutes ago      Up 39 seconds       8123/tcp, 9000/tcp, 9009/tcp   sentry_onpremise_clickhouse_1
a61f8b22b8a1        postgres:9.6                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 minutes ago      Up 39 seconds       5432/tcp                       sentry_onpremise_postgres_1
2f75d656f1ba        redis:5.0-alpine                       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 minutes ago      Up 40 seconds       6379/tcp                       sentry_onpremise_redis_1
2b5844a12937        getsentry/symbolicator:latest          "/bin/bash /docker-e…"   23 minutes ago      Up 39 seconds       3021/tcp                       sentry_onpremise_symbolicator_1
```

What's the problem? Where should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was - the SSL certificate! It was expired.
So events could not be sent silently.

Reissued the certificate and everything's is fine now!